# Where can I save video file created by camera plugin on Android & IOS?

Tags: flutter, file, dart, mobile, camera

I'm using camera plugin in my flutter dart app. to record videos.

I would like to view the files on my mobile.
Where can I save video mp4 files and how to save?

I'm saving with filename.save(path) and I can see the files in directory.
I also can see the xfile in the directory returned from stopvideo.

I can see the files by printing the folders
but I can not see in browser + enable hidden files.

```
///init
      appDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      videoDirectory = '${appDirectory.path}';
      await Directory(videoDirectory).create(recursive: true);
      final String currentTime = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
      filePath = '$videoDirectory/${currentTime}.mp4';

///code    
      videoFile = await controller.stopVideoRecording();
      print ("XXXX videoFile-"+videoFile.path);
      print (Directory("/data/user/0/com.flutter_app_camera1/cache").listSync());
      print (Directory("/data/user/0/com.flutter_app_camera1/cache").listSync().length.toString());
    
    
      await videoFile.saveTo(filePath);
      print ("(XXXX filePath-"+filePath);
      print (Directory(videoDirectory).listSync());
      print (Directory(videoDirectory).listSync().length.toString());
```

///Prints

```
    I/flutter (20330): XXXX videoFile-/data/user/0/com.flutter_app_camera1/cache/REC3520996093112925184.mp4
    I/flutter (20330): [File: '/data/user/0/com.flutter_app_camera1/cache/REC3520996093112925184.mp4']
    I/flutter (20330): 1
    I/flutter (20330): (XXXX filePath-/data/user/0/com.flutter_app_camera1/app_flutter/1618663350463.mp4
    I/flutter (20330): [Directory: '/data/user/0/com.flutter_app_camera1/app_flutter/flutter_assets', File: '/data/user/0/com.flutter_app_camera1/app_flutter/res_timestamp-1-1618663045614', File: '/data/user/0/com.flutter_app_camera1/app_flutter/1618663350463.mp4']
    I/flutter (20330): 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If would like to view the files on your mobile, you can use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver) gallery_saver plugin to save your video file in Gallery.

```
final video = await controller.stopVideoRecording();
await GallerySaver.saveVideo(video.path);
```